# Computing the center of mass of a signal using the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I am having difficulty with a homework problem which asks:

[image]

I have some ideas in mind but I have no clue as to whether they are correct or not. Below is my attempt:

[image]

Comment: This seems very much like a homework problem or self-study problem. These are on-topic here, BUT we prefer you to include your attempt (no matter whether you think it's right or not). Upload a picture of your working if that helps. I'll re-open (or another mod will) once that's done.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I have uploaded what I think the answer is.

Comment: Not really what you're asking, but that is not a sensible definition of the center of mass of a signal. More sensible definitions would use either $|x|$ or $|x|^2$ in place of $x$.

Comment: @user34067, I just noticed that there's a minus sign missing in the exponent in your first equation for X.

Comment: I don't think your formula for the spectral centroid is correct. Please, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_centroid. Anyway, I have a c++ implementaion and even if you don't use c++ it should be fairly easy to convert it to whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you do is correct. You can calculate the sum of all the values of a signal evaluating its DTFT at $\omega=0$.

When you try to express the numerator with the DTFT though, you make a pretty clever thing but it is not correct, because you are evaluating the DTFT at $\omega=\ln\left( n^{\frac{1}{j2\pi n}}\right)$, which is not always real-valued. Remember that $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$.

To find how the DTFT of $x(n)$ and the numerator of $c$ are related, you can use the following property:

$$x(n)\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}X(\omega) \implies nx(n)\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}j\frac{dX(\omega)}{d\omega}$$

Using this property and your approach for the denominator (evaluating the transform at $\omega=0$), you should get the desired result.